# Unable to access variable user from template in django 1.10

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I'm new to `django`. I'm implementing user `login` mechanism in my app. When log the user in i can verify by opening admin app if the user is logged in or not and the user does log in. Now when i try to give user a message for example `{{ Hello user.username }}` i am getting nothing. Below is my complete code.

**view.py**

```
def login_user(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == "POST":
        login_username = request.POST['username']
        login_password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=login_username,password=login_password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/albums/')
            else:
                print "Your Account is disabled"
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(login_username, login_password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        return render(request,'music/login.html',{},context)
```

**albums.html**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <h1>hello {{ user.username }}!</h1>
        {% else %}
            <h1>hello world!</h1>
        {% endif %}
```

Help me, i am using Django version 1.10 with python 2.7

Comment: Which view is using `index.html` template? Because the code above just shows that after login the page redirects to `/albums/`. Are you also not getting `hello world!`?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited. it's not index.html, it's album.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you haven't provided `user` variable in template context. So either add `user` variable into your context in the view.

```
# views.py
# ...
def login_user(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == "POST":
        login_username = request.POST['username']
        login_password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=login_username,password=login_password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/albums/')
            else:
                print "Your Account is disabled"
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(login_username, login_password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        context['user'] = user
        return render(request,'music/login.html',{},context)
```

Or

Try accessing

```
request.user
```

instead. Generally `request` variable is added to context automatically by context processor.

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1>hello {{ request.user.username }}!</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>hello world!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sure. My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you pass an empty context to your template. Try this:

```
return render(request,'music/login.html',{'user':user})
```